# pgfplots adjust style given string/class value from a table `scatter/@pre marker code/.code `

Tags: pgfplots, conditionals

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524508/modify-multiple-style-parameters-of-a-pgfplot-scatter-with-visualization-depends), I would like to set the style (color/shape) of scatter points, depending on the value of a certain column read from a table.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                z buffer=sort
            ]
            \addplot3+[
                %scatter/classes={ a={mark=square*, red}, b={mark=square*, blue}}, % this line fails
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{x}\as\x},
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{y}\as\y},
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{z}\as\z},
                visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{4} \as \label},
                scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
                \def\markopts{
                    mark size=(\x+\y)/3+2,%
                    % color=red if \label == a else blue, % I don't know how to handle this
                    opacity=\z
                    }
                    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
                },
                scatter/@post marker code/.code={
                    \endscope
                },
            ] table[x=x, y=y, z=z, meta=label, col sep=space] {
                x   y   z   label
                0   0   0.1 a
                0   1   0.5 b
                1.2 0   1.0 a
                2   5   0.7 a
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I assume the `scatter/classes={}` line cannot work because the macros `@pre` and `@post` are re-defined, but then, how to handle the string comparison for each classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\thisrowno{4}` is incorrect, because column indexing in `pgfplots` table input starts from 0. So, `\thisrowno{3}` would work, but I prefer using `\thisrow{label}` as this is more readable and allows you to later insert columns in your table without breaking the code.

Other than that, once you have the label in macro `\myLabel`, you can use an `expl3` function such as `\str_case_e:nnF` to implement a switch-case string comparison with fallback:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Like \let, but errors out if \strCase is already defined
\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case_e:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

...

\def\markopts{
  mark size=(\x+\y)/3+2,
  color/.expanded={\strCase{\myLabel}{{a}{red}
                                      {b}{blue}}{green}},
  ...
}
```

Here, `green` is the fallback value used in case the label of a point is neither `a` nor `b`. You can add as many cases as you want. Please note that `\strCase` works inside `color/.expanded={...}` because it is an alias for `expl3`'s `\str_case_e:nnF` function, which is *fully expandable* (this fact is documented in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), where there is a full star next to the macro name in the margin).

## First example

Here is a complete code that programmatically sets the marker color in a label-dependent way. If you have several style elements to set for each label type, I suggest a slightly different technique for more readability—see the second example below.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.15}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Like \let, but errors out if \strCase is already defined
\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case_e:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[z buffer=sort]
            \addplot3+[
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{x}\as\x},
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{y}\as\y},
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{z}\as\z},
                visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \myLabel},
                scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
                  \def\markopts{%
                    mark size=(\x+\y)/3+2,
                    color/.expanded={\strCase{\myLabel}{{a}{red}
                                                        {b}{blue}}{green}},
                    opacity=\z,
                  }%
                  \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
                },
                scatter/@post marker code/.code={
                  \endscope
                },
            ] table[x=x, y=y, z=z, meta=label, col sep=space] {
                x   y   z   label
                0   0   0.1 a
                0   1   0.5 b
                1.2 0   1.0 a
                2   5   0.7 a
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: In this particular case, if the `expl3` version on your system is too old to have `\str_case_e:nnF`, the `\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case_e:nnF` line can be replaced with:

```latex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }
\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case:VnF
```

(`\str_case:VnF` is *not* equivalent to `\str_case_e:nnF`, but it is adequate for our needs here).

## Second example

In this second example, we want to set several mark style attributes (PGF keys) in a label-dependent way. This is possible using the previous technique, but would lead to a lot of redundancy:

```latex
\def\markopts{
    mark size=(\x+\y)/3+2,
    color/.expanded={\strCase{\myLabel}{{a}{red}
                                        {b}{blue}}{green}},
    mark/.expanded={\strCase{\myLabel}{{a}{triangle*}
                                        {b}{square*}}{x}},
    ...,
}
```

So, I propose a slightly different technique that allows one to set several PGF keys at once when dealing with each case:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.15}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }
\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case:VnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[z buffer=sort]
            \addplot3+[
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{x}\as\x},
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{y}\as\y},
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{z}\as\z},
                visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \myLabel},
                scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
                  \edef\markopts{%
                    \strCase{\myLabel}
                      {
                        {a}{mark=triangle*, color=red}
                        {b}{mark=square*, color=blue}
                      }
                      {mark=x, color=green}, % fallback
                    mark size=(\x+\y)/3+2,
                    opacity=\z,
                  }%
                  \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
                },
                scatter/@post marker code/.code={
                  \endscope
                },
            ] table[x=x, y=y, z=z, meta=label, col sep=space] {
                x   y   z   label
                0   0   0.1 a
                0   1   0.5 b
                1.2 0   1.0 a
                2   5   0.7 a
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

In case you have macros (“sensitive material”) in the label-dependent code that musn't be expanded too early (namely, at the time where `\strCase` is itself expanded), you can protect the sensitive material from the expansion performed by `\edef` using either `\noexpand` or `\unexpanded`, for instance:

```latex
\strCase{\myLabel}
  {
    {a}{mark=triangle*, \unexpanded{〈sensitive balanced text〉}}
    {b}{mark=square*, foo=\noexpand〈sensitiveToken〉}
  }
  {mark=x, color=green},
\unexpanded{%
  foo=bar,
  baz=quux,
}%
```

Here, 〈sensitiveToken〉 could be a macro or an active character, whereas 〈sensitive balanced text〉 can consist of arbitrarily many tokens.

Comment: Thanks very mutch for your answer. Unfortunately, your code snipped doesn't compile for me: `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \strCase`. My version of latex: Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 1 January 2015, version: 4.41. My version of pdfTex: pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

Comment: Presumably, you omitted `\usepackage{expl3}` or `\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case_e:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff`, or both. This is where `\strCase` is defined. If your `expl3` is too old to have `\str_case_e:nnF`, you can use this instead (here): `\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }
\cs_new_eq:NN \strCase \str_case:VnF
\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: If this fails, post the full LaTeX output, e.g. on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: The issue was probably expl3 version because your second strCase definition works. Thanks !

Comment: Could you add a line for the marker shape as well please ? Thank you very mutch

Comment: nevermind, I managed to do it :-) Thank you

Comment: I added a better way to set several PGF keys in each case for the label. I'd suggest you read the latest version of the answer (I also removed the `scatter/classes={a={mark=square*, red}, b={mark=square*, blue}}` which wasn't useful anymore).

Comment: very much appreciated !